# Select an element inside a p-dropdown tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select

I am trying to select the 200 option on a p-dropdown using Selenium and Python with this function getting a timeout exception with no message...

```
Selection = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'ui-dropdown-') and @aria-label='200']"))))
Selection.select_by_value("200")
```

the dropdown menu looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-dropdown-items-wrapper" style="max-height: 200px;">
    <ul class="ui-dropdown-items ui-dropdown-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset" role="listbox">
        <p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c10-0 ng-star-inserted" style="">
            <li role="option" class="ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" aria-label="25">
                <span class="ng-star-inserted">25</span>
            </li>
        </p-dropdownitem>
        <p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c10-0 ng-star-inserted" style="">
            <li role="option" class="ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all" aria-label="50">
                <span class="ng-star-inserted">50</span>
            </li>
        </p-dropdownitem>
        <p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c10-0 ng-star-inserted" style="">
            <li role="option" class="ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all" aria-label="100">
                <span class="ng-star-inserted">100</span>
            </li>
        </p-dropdownitem>
        <p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c10-0 ng-star-inserted" style="">
            <li role="option" class="ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all" aria-label="200">
                <span class="ng-star-inserted">200</span>
            </li>
        </p-dropdownitem>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone knows or can throw me a bone on how can I select the 200 option to show all the registers in just one page and avoid the initial pagination?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Select() works if the elements are in a `select` tag.

Collect the `p` elements and iterate for the right option.

```
    options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".../p")
    for o in options:
    ...
```

Or click on the drop down and click on the required option.

Answer (score 0):

This is not `Select` type if you pass this element to the `Select` it will throw the Exception `UnexpectedTagNameException` internally its constructor perform check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag. If it is not, then an `UnexpectedTagNameException` is thrown.

Based on the provide HTML source if you can check with the below XPath

```
((//div[@class='ui-dropdown-items-wrapper']//li)[4])

 element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//div[@class='ui-dropdown-items-wrapper']//li)[4])")

print(element.get_attribute("aria-label")

you can enhance the code as per your requirement
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried your code but throws an error message:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"((//div[@class='ui-dropdown-items-wrapper']//li)[4])"}

Maybe could find the element in a different way?

Comment: @efe Okay, So can you share the URL for this, it might help

Comment: thanks for your reply, unfortunately it's the private area from the Vuforia portal (https://developer.vuforia.com/) and you need an account to access it. maybe I could copy and paste the code showing on the Chrome console? otherwise I don't know how to share it properly.

Comment: I think I see maybe where is the problem... when you enter to the page, initially the the HTML code is not showing all the values inside the pagination combo. It's just showing this:
`
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<input class="ng-tns-c11-1" aria-haspopup="listbox" readonly="" type="text" aria-label="25"></div>
<label class="ng-tns-c11-1 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted">25</label>
`
I think I'll try a different way, for instance trying to sort the values of the table clicking on the "sort by date" span using the EC.element_to_be_clickable